# Why is acting on homosexuality a sin?

Tags: homosexuality

Homosexual relationship is the only sin that satisfies these conditions:

1. It is natural and dispositional, in that one does not "prefer" to go homo, they are simply born this way. (EDIT: having a homosexual relationship is not a disposition, it is acting on said disposition. However, I would say that this is the natural and harmless way, as defended below)
2. It is harmless to all parties. One may retaliate by mentioning the "harm to society, family structure etc." but I see these answers as rhetorical since the acceptance of homosexuality doesn't mean we must abolish traditional family structures, and the harm to society is purely subjective as the only rationale for this argument is the fact that homosexuality is a sin. If it were not, I don't believe any Muslim would be concerned about this issue. I haven't come across any secular research that portrays gay people as "a threat".
3. It is not achieved through exploitation, unlike in the case of incest. Even though both parties are consenting, the possibility of grooming remains in an incest relationship. This is not applicable to a standard homosexual relationship. (and I doubt incest is dispositional, so there's that)

There are still some discussions about the word بَلۡ and its implications about the "true meaning" of the verse 7:81 and similar verses, but I will go with the orthodox opinion here, unless someone can convince me that that there are indeed wider discussions about the status of homosexual relationships in Islam.

One may make an argument by pointing out that "we all have our own tests". I can divide these "tests" to two categories:

1. The situation we're born into: being a child of a poor or rich parent, being blind, not having a body part etc. However, these tests are vastly different from homosexuality because you don't have to act against them. I find it hard to explain my position because it surpasses my knowledge of English, so I'll just do a comparision: The restriction on homosexual relationships is more similar to being forced to not use one of your legs, for example, even though it's perfectly healthy.
2. The "minor" tests, to be honest, that applies to all Muslims; stuff like not having sex before marriage (note that homosexuals don't have an 'endgame' in this aspect, since they can't get married), not eating pork and not drinking. Eating something other than bacon or abstaining from recreational drugs won't cause you to have psychological issues or greatly deteriorate your quality of life (provided you're willingly making these choices), but being forced to living a celibate life for no apparent reason (note that other orientations such as pedophilia or beastiality do harm living beings) will.

So why exactly is acting on a totally harmless trait one can't shake off considered a sin? And please don't get me wrong: I'm not asking these questions to ridicule Islam, I'm actually trying to symphatize with it.

Answer (score 5):

Allah is the only one who can decide what is or is not a sin, and He is under no obligation to explain why. It doesn't matter how many arguments you make or refute, or how harmless you think it is, none of us has any authority to change that.

You dismiss vague aphorisms like "we all have our own tests", but that's really all we can provide with any certainty: Explaining why Allah has decreed anything when He Himself hasn't explained it is speculation at best.

In short, if Allah says it's a sin, then it's a sin. That's why.

Comment: I understand that this is the case for Muslims but here's the thing: this condemnation of homosexuality has affected many people both Muslim and Non-Muslim and put them through suffery. Would it be too much for me to ask for an objective reason for all this misery?

Comment: @BerkenTekin If one is not Muslim, then the Islamic concept of sin is meaningless. Something being a sin is entirely tangential to any actions or condemnation that may come from acting on it; that is a whole other issue, often more political than anything, and probably way too complex to be on-topic here.

Comment: @BerkenTekin “suffery” ? If I hadn’t been obligated to perform wishes of ALLAH(c.c.) , I’d asked myself for what I’ve created. If I can do whatever I want in the World, why do we come from the paradise while we were in there? If I can do whatever I want in the World, why do we need to be subject to the examination? I don’t want the topic to make longer, the key point is that Islam is to consent.

Comment: @snr I don't know if you're gay or not and this might not be applicable to you but as a straight person, I'm seeing and hearing about what the gay population of Muslim countries (such as mine) go through. It is indeed utter misery the way these guys are treated.

Please don't get this wrong but have you ever thought about why straight men get to have up to four wives and numerous concubines while gay people who are just as natural and valid (big IMO) get nothing? Like I get that "God said so" but I'm more interested in rational, secular arguments against homosexual relations.

Comment: @BerkenTekin Islam is a religion, not a secular philosophy. And Muslims are followers of Islam, not of a secular philosophy. So, Islam has no concern in providing secular arguments. And Muslims are not (or should not be) concerned with needing secular arguments to implement laws.

Comment: @TheZ perhaps I used the wrong word for this. By secular, I mean reasons that can be found plausible by the general population, not just the Muslims. It doesn't have to be completely out of scope of Islamic jurisprudence.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a serious reason. You know the Quran passage as I do as well. The same is said in the Tanakh, Jews have the same law forbidding homosexuality. However, neither in the Qur'an nor in the Tanakh nor in the hadith (as far as I know) is a hint what gay or lesbian believers should do in their lives. I see a need to discuss this in society without any religous base as it's not a choice but a destiny for some persons and tries to "heal" this have come out vain.
Discussion among Christians show a debate, but Christianity is not a law-giving religion, it does not accept the Qur'an and is not clear about the Tanakh.
Hence, this discussion has to be started from an other base in Islam. The discussion inside Judaism may help. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality_and_Judaism
However, a question and answer site like this is not the best platform to discuss this issue.
I am sorry that I can not give you an answer that differs from what you already know.